# pyqt gui passing argument to a python function

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I used qt Designer to generate my code. I want to have my 5 text boxes to pass 5 arguments to a python function(the function is not in this code) when the run button is released. I'm not really sure how to do this, I'm very new to pyqt.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.runText = ""
        self.scriptText = ""
        self.changeText = ""
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(580, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.Run = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Run.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 150, 75, 23))
        self.Run.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Run"))
        self.Script = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Script.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 10, 46, 13))
        self.Script.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Script"))
        self.Hosts = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Hosts.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 10, 46, 13))
        self.Hosts.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Hosts"))
        self.CHange = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CHange.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 10, 46, 13))
        self.CHange.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("CHange"))
        self.ScriptLine = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.ScriptLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 113, 20))
        self.ScriptLine.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ScriptLine"))
        self.HostLine = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.HostLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 30, 113, 20))
        self.HostLine.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("HostLine"))
        self.ChangeLine = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.ChangeLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 30, 113, 20))
        self.ChangeLine.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.ChangeLine.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ChangeLine"))
        self.Cla = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Cla.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 80, 211, 16))
        self.Cla.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Cla.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Cla"))
        self.Sla = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Sla.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 100, 211, 16))
        self.Sla.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Sla.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Sla"))
        self.Hla = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Hla.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 120, 201, 16))
        self.Hla.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Hla.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Hla"))
        self.Cla_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Cla_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 60, 111, 16))
        self.Cla_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Cla_2"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 100, 46, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 46, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 80, 46, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 80, 113, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Wingdings 2"))
        font.setPointSize(1)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 81, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 60, 46, 13))
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ScriptLine, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.Sla.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.HostLine, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.Hla.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ChangeLine, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.Cla.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Run, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("released()")), self.ScriptLine.clear)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Run, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("released()")), self.HostLine.clear)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Run, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("released()")), self.ChangeLine.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.Run.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run", None))
        self.Script.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Script", None))
        self.Hosts.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hosts", None))
        self.CHange.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change", None))
        self.ScriptLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter script file name", None))
        self.HostLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Host file name", None))
        self.ChangeLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Change file name", None))
        self.Cla_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Files to be used:", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Script:", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hosts:", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change:", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "User Name", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you precise how the command line looks like (ie: `prog_name script host change` or `prog_name script username:password@host change`) ?

Comment: Sorry this was not a command line that you want to invoke. Can you precise what is the signature of the function ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this code will suit your needs:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(366, 185)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.Script = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Script.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Script.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Script"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Script, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Hosts = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Hosts.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Hosts.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Hosts"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Hosts, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Change = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Change.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Change.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Change"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Change, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.ScriptLine = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.ScriptLine.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ScriptLine"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ScriptLine, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.HostLine = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.HostLine.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("HostLine"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.HostLine, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.ChangeLine = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.ChangeLine.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ChangeLine"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ChangeLine, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_6, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.label_8 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_8"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.label_7 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_7"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.label_9 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_9"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.Cla = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Cla.setText("")
        self.Cla.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Cla"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Cla)
        self.Sla = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Sla.setText("")
        self.Sla.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Sla"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Sla)
        self.Hla = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Hla.setText("")
        self.Hla.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Hla"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Hla)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 2, 1, 3, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.userName = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.userName.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("userName"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.userName, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.passWord = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.passWord.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.passWord.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("passWord"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.passWord, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(109, 52, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 4, 0, 2, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(109, 52, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 4, 2, 2, 1)
        self.Run = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Run.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Run"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Run, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ScriptLine, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.Sla.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.HostLine, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.Hla.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ChangeLine, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.Cla.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Run, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("released()")), MainWindow.run)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.Script.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Script", None))
        self.Hosts.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Hosts", None))
        self.Change.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Change", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Use Name", None))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Files to be used:", None))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Change:", None))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Script:", None))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Hosts:", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Password", None))
        self.Run.setText(_translate(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"), "Run", None))
        #self.ScriptLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter script file name", None))
        #self.HostLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Host file name", None))
        #self.ChangeLine.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Change file name", None))

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.runText = ""
        self.scriptText = ""
        self.changeText = ""
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.runText = "{0}:{1}@{2}".format(str(self.ui.userName.text()),str(self.ui.passWord.text()),str(self.ui.HostLine.text()))
        self.scriptText = str(self.ui.ScriptLine.text())
        self.changeText = str(self.ui.ChangeLine.text())

        my_function(self.runText, self.scriptText, self.changeText)

        self.ui.ScriptLine.clear()
        self.ui.HostLine.clear()
        self.ui.ChangeLine.clear()

def my_function(*args):
    print "Function args:"
    for arg in args:
        print arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myMainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    myMainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your own functions to signals like this:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Run, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("released()")), self.yourNewFunction)
```

After that you can just call the values of the lineEdits:

```
def yourNewFunction(self):
    print self.lineEdit.text()
```

By the way you're using old style Signals which are no longer supported in pyqt5. Plus new style is much easier to read:

```
self.Run.pressed.connect(self.yourNewFunction)
```